# Equals method in AbstractSet in Java

Tags: java

I am curious to know the reason why the `equals` method in the `AbstractSet` typecasts the object `o` to `Collection` instead of `Set`. If it cast to `Set`, it would not make any difference considering all of the implementing classes of `Set` inherit from `AbstractCollection` directly or indirectly. Is there any specific reason for this ? [Link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/AbstractSet.java#AbstractSet.equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: SO really works better when you keep it to 1 question per post.  Could you make a short program showing how you think #1 should go?

Comment: #2: the abstract class provides an implementation for the interface method.

Comment: Both questions are based on an obviously very wrong understanding of class inheritance and interface implementations in Java and do not really make sense as you have asked them. I think you should read up on that subject instead. Short explanation: 1 - the difference is irrelevant, 2 - the method is inherited from AbstractCollection class and not from the Set interface.

Comment: Removing question 2.

Comment: If you notice, `AbstractSet#equals()` returns quickly if `o` is not a `Set`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are correct in assuming that there is no semantic difference. The use of `Collection` in the cast rather than `Set` is possibly due to the principle of using the least specific type - the same principle that you see in declarations such as `Set<Foo> fooSet = new HashSet<>();`. Only methods from a `Collection` are needed, so we cast to a `Collection`. This is, however, an insignificant implementation detail that is not defined by the JLS.
2. (deleted question) An interface merely states that certain behaviour (methods) should be present in all implementations. If a class extends an abstract class that provides this behaviour as well as implementing an interface, this is fine as the class has the required behaviour present. Its actual implementation is derived from the abstract class.